# When exception class in c++ initialized?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, object, exception

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;

struct MyException : public exception {
   const char * what () const throw () {
      return "C++ Exception";
   }
};

int main() {
   try {
      throw MyException();
   } catch(MyException& e) {
      std::cout << "MyException caught" << std::endl;
      std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
   } catch(std::exception& e) {
           //Other errors
   }
}
```

In above program, initializing MyException class is done in catch function parameter as `catch(MyException& e)` and initialization can also be done without `&` symbol. 
My doubt is object of MyException class really created when `&` is used? What is the trick here?

Comment: No, `MyException` is constructed at `throw MyException();` line. In catch you only, you know, catch it. Perhaps you confuse "initialization" with "declaration"?

Answer (score 0):

the initialization happens here:

```
 throw MyException();
```

because there you are creating a new instance of the class MyException...

anonymous instance (the object is not assigned to any variable declared by you) but there is the point where the constructor of your class is invoked and in consequence the initialization.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special about exception classes. They're simply classes. Yes, they are **intended** to be used to communicate exception information, but any type can be used for that. So don't get hung up on the exception code itself; it has nothing to do with when the object is created. `return MyException();` would create an object of type `MyException`. So does `throw MyException();`.